# Color gradient not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

Ok my problem is that in firefox my hover gradient is showing up as black to white. Black being the top color and white as the bottom. Here is the css hover code I'm using. It doesn't make sense to me because I'm not even using the color codes for black or white. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
nav a {
color: #fff;
background: #b9b9b9; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #b9b9b9 0%, #616161 99%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#b9b9b9), color-stop(99%,#616161)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #b9b9b9 0%,#616161 99%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #b9b9b9 0%,#616161 99%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #b9b9b9 0%,#616161 99%); /* IE10+ */



nav a:hover, nav a:active {
background: #b9b9b9; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #4f4f4f, #b9b9b9 ); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #b9b9b9 0%,#4f4f4f 99%); /* 
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #b9b9b9 0%,#4f4f4f 99%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #b9b9b9 0%,#4f4f4f 99%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #b9b9b9 0%,#4f4f4f 99%); /* W3C */
```

Comment: Uh ... are you sure you aren't just missing your closing brace? You have `nav a {` but no `}`.

Comment: the first of those two sets of styles doesn't have the un-prefixed `linear-gradient`. You should make sure you include that.

Comment: @mbratch The ***nav*** tag is new in HTML5...

Comment: Thanks War10ck, I hadn't learned that yet. Much obliged.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing your closing braces.

Your code works otherwise: http://jsfiddle.net/66QQV/

```
nav a
{
    color: #fff;
    background: #b9b9b9; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #b9b9b9 0%, #616161 99%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#b9b9b9), color-stop(99%,#616161)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #b9b9b9 0%,#616161 99%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #b9b9b9 0%,#616161 99%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #b9b9b9 0%,#616161 99%); /* IE10+ */
}


nav a:hover, nav a:active
{
    background: #b9b9b9; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #4f4f4f, #b9b9b9 ); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #b9b9b9 0%,#4f4f4f 99%); /* 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #b9b9b9 0%,#4f4f4f 99%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #b9b9b9 0%,#4f4f4f 99%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #b9b9b9 0%,#4f4f4f 99%); /* W3C */
}
```

This is assuming that you intend to put an `<a>` element inside of a `<nav>` element ... if you meant for this to be a class or an ID (such as `<span class="nav">` or `<div id="nav">`), you need to use `.nav` or `#nav` instead, respectively.

Comment: There was more code that I intentionally left out. But I just found the problem. I had a duplicate nav a:hover somewhere in the style sheet. Thanks anyways guys and gals! :)